# Resizing dynamic arrays

Tags: c++

Can somebody point out the problem with this code (for resizing a dynamic array). I am using Visual Studio 2013 to run the code. It gives a runtime error i.e. `heap corruption detected after normal block (a number) at (memory address). CRT detected that the application wrote to the memory after the end of heap buffer`.
I am to use the technique mentioned below and not any standard library function or vector for resizing the array:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int * rg(int *, int, int);

int main()
{
    int len = 1;
    int * x = new int[len];

    int i = 0;
    int y = 0;
    while (getchar() != 'q')
    {
        cin >> y;
        if (i == 0)
            x[0] = y;
        else
        {
            x = rg(x, len, y);
            len++;
        }
        cout << len;
        i++;
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << endl;
    }
}

int * rg(int*x, int len, int val)
{
    int * temp = x;
    x = new int[];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        x[i] = temp[i];
    }
    x[len] = val;

    delete[]temp;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: You don't use any length information for creating the new `x`. Also please try to format the code correctly so that we can see easier what is going on.

Comment: Whenever you think about "dynamic arrays" when programming in C++, your next thought should *always* be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Using the standard library and its classes and functions will make your life as a C++ programmer *so* much easier.

Comment: Is this homework? If not use std::vector.

Comment: The problem is that you're not using **`std::vector`**.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = new int[];
```

is invalid as standard C++ and shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include library that has `getchar`. Add `#include <cstdio>` at the beginning.

Second thing is that after grabbing the first number you don't increase `len`, which causes the second input overwrite the first one. The last input is doubled at the end.

Third. When allocating memory, the compiler needs to know how much it has to allocate. You need to specify that in `x = new int[]`.